# How to open google login dialog in the same window instead of popup window?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I have website where users can login with their google account. I am using javascript google api.login method to display google login dialog. By default, it triggers displaying new popup window

How to open google login dialog to be displayed in the same window where the user clicked on google Login button?

```
   my code is like-- 

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=render" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function render() {
        gapi.signin.render('customBtn', {

            'callback': 'onSignInCallback',
            'clientid': 'my-client-id',
            'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
            'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function onSignInCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['access_token']) {
            // The user is signed in
            var loc = '/account/SignInAsGoogleUser?accessToken=' + authResult['access_token'];
            window.location.href = loc;

        } else if (authResult['error']) {           
        }      
    }
</script>
<div class="align-center Google_Login_Btn">
    <div id="gSignInWrapper">
        <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
            <span class="buttonText">Log in With Google</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code please ?

Comment: my code is in above text area block. which i am using for google sign in feature. Thanks